# Php soap extension configuration on Windows

Tags: php, soap

I have a problem to configure a soap extension on windows7.

In apache acesss error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\Php\ext\php_soap.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`

I was looking on google, and other, put some versions of soap dll files. Nothing to work. I also changed a extension dir to other.

And i also get apache error:

> entry point php_output_discard could not be located in the dynamic link libary php5ts.dll

Where is a problem? I use a VertrigoServ prebuild web server.

**Fixed: Need use soap .dll for right php version.**

Comment: Can you load other extensions? Maybe it's a rights thing. `Program Files` can be problematic on Windows.

Comment: Never really heard of `VertigoServ` but I do have allot of experience using with this http://www.wampserver.com/en/ - easy to install (install it here: `C:\wamp` - program files are bad location). Works out of the box and has ALL the php DLLs you'll need.